# When appending an <option></option> in jQuery, how to set selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, I empty a `<select>` element and rebuild it again with available times.

However I am trying to set the `<option>` to selected if it matches the previously selected time:

```
if(time == currenttime) {
    console.log("Matched Time "+currenttime);
    $("#time-start").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", time).text(time)).prop("selected","selected");
} else {
    $("#time-start").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", time).text(time));
}
```

I get the console message `Matched Time` but the `.prop("selected","selected")` isn't setting the newly created option to be selected.

How can I set it to be selected?

Comment: you are chaining `.prop()` to the `.append()` call, `.append()` returns the original chained jQuery object, not the appended element. So you are actually trying to set "selected" on the `<select>` element and not the `<option>` element.

Comment: Append all the options first, then just call `$('#time-start').val(time)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code will get more readable like this (and thus makes it easier to set the `selected` property at the right place):

```
let $opt = $("<option></option>").attr("value", time).text(time);
if(time == currenttime) {
    console.log("Matched Time "+currenttime);
    $opt.prop("selected","selected");
}
$("#time-start").append($opt);
```

Comment: That works! Just for so i can learn, how is that different from setting it inline as I did above?

Comment: @Chud37 Have a look at your parenthesis. In your code you set the `selected` property on the `#time-start` element and not on the `<option>`.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, set `selected` with `option` element

```
var option = $("<option>", {"selected" : time == currenttime, text: time, value: time });
$("#time-start").append(option );
```

OR, Use `.val()`

```
$("#time-start").val(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to following:

```
$("#time-start").append($("<option></option>").prop("selected",true).attr("value", time).text(time));
```